# Combining multiple $samples in single aggregate query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate-functions

I am working on a query to retrieve sample documents from mongodb using a condition and with sample size

```
db.getCollection('questionBank').aggregate(
   [{"$match":{"difficultyLevel":"Intermediate"}}, { $sample: { size: 5 } } 
   ]
)

db.getCollection('questionBank').aggregate(
       [{"$match":{"difficultyLevel":"Low"}}, { $sample: { size: 3 } } 
       ]
    )


db.getCollection('questionBank').aggregate(
           [{"$match":{"difficultyLevel":"High"}}, { $sample: { size: 2 } } 
           ]
        )
```

I want to have a set of records from question bank with difficulty level Imtermediate,5  Low,3 and High,2
I am able to get all these records using three separate aggregate queries and i am merging the 3 query results to an array.

Is there a way to do this in a single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. `$facet` and `$project` will do that for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "Intermediate": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "difficultyLevel": "Intermediate"
          }
        },
        {
          $sample: {
            size: 3
          }
        }
      ],
      "Low": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "difficultyLevel": "Low"
          }
        },
        {
          $sample: {
            size: 2
          }
        }
      ],
      "High": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "difficultyLevel": "High"
          }
        },
        {
          $sample: {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      merged_results: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$Intermediate",
          "$Low",
          "$High"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/h981En8lJBo

Comment: This works fine.. thankyou.. Is there a way to mix the questions in the merged results.. As of now it is coming as Intermediate,Intermediate,Intermediate,High,High,Low. Is there a way to randomize the array.. so that question difficulties are mixed

Comment: @slaveCoder There is certainly a way, but you would need to create a shuffling function in mongodb and call it from your aggregation, which is fairly complicated. So there is no native "$shuffle" method in mongo aggregation. Personally, I would shuffle it in the app (Node, PHP, etc), because it's so much easier.